# Git Does Not Affect Changes After Commit

Tags: linux, git, debian

This is my first time trying to work with version control. As I found one of the best solution is Git.

I did almost everything correct and at least i got some problem or something like that.

Debian Machine.

**/home/user/myProject/**

```
git init --bare myproject.git
```

**/var/www/clonedProject/**

```
git clone /home/user/myProject/myproject.git
git add xxx.php
git commit -m "TEST"
git push origin master
```

but there is no changes in home/user/myProject. I don't understand what is problem about, if there is problem or what i am doing wrong.

[Git documentation](http://rogerdudler.github.io/git-guide/)

Thanks.

Comment: What do you mean by "there is no changes"?  What does that mean? How are you checking?

Comment: Do you _have_ a file named `xxx.php`?

Comment: I think, (maybe i say stupideness) but changes must be affected in /home/user/myProject/ folder, my goal is to make small server, work with version control and save the best versions in production server.

Comment: What do you mean "changes must be affected"?  You're making a bare repo there, so what do you expect to see?

Comment: I have 2 files, named index.html. nothing happens.

Comment: What's the output from all of the commands you ran?  Everything you have there looks fine.

Comment: yes and debian also tells me everything is fine. how can i check if something's wrong?

Comment: See my answer for a complete example log showing how your steps look fine.  Some assumptions - `xxx.php` exists and is in the right place, and that you have the correct permissions set everywhere.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a complete test run using your example (as close as reasonably possible, anyway).  You can see from this log that your commands should be working fine.  If you get some different output, please share it with us so we can help you solve your real problem.  Step by step:

1. create some directories to work with for this example

   ```
   $ mkdir bare
   $ mkdir clone
   ```
2. initialize a bare repo called `myproject.git`

   ```
   $ cd bare/
   $ git init --bare myproject.git
   Initialized empty Git repository in /example/bare/myproject.git/
   ```
3. change to the `clone` directory and clone the repo we just created

   ```
   $ cd ../clone
   $ git clone ../bare/myproject.git
   Cloning into 'myproject'...
   warning: You appear to have cloned an empty repository.
   done.
   ```
4. change directory into the new repo, then create, add, and commit a new file

   ```
   $ cd myproject/
   $ touch xxx.php
   $ git add xxx.php
   $ git commit -m "TEST"
   [master (root-commit) 921786a] TEST
    1 file changed, 0 insertions(+), 0 deletions(-)
    create mode 100644 xxx.php
   ```
5. push this new commit back to origin (the bare repo we cloned from earlier)

   ```
   $ git push origin master             # push this new commit to origin
   Counting objects: 3, done.
   Writing objects: 100% (3/3), 207 bytes, done.
   Total 3 (delta 0), reused 0 (delta 0)
   To /example/clone/../bare/myproject.git
    * [new branch]      master -> master
   ```
6. go back to the bare repo and see if the commit is there

   ```
   $ cd ../../bare/myproject.git/
   $ git log
   commit 921786a20f3e7e0d17eec65450472b54bf3d7c56
   Author: Carl Norum <carl@someplaceorother.com>
   Date:   Wed Jul 3 08:00:31 2013 -0700

       TEST
   ```
7. It is, so everything worked fine.

Comment: yes, absolutely 1 to 1 correct. everything works like u wrote. so? how can i check? where is my changes affected? if i change something in clone folder, what will happen in bare? thank thanks

Comment: A bare repo is just that - bare.  The files aren't checked out for use like a normal clone, where there's a filesystem copy of everything for you to work with.  A bare repo is basically just the contents of the `.git` folder from a normal repo.  If you make changes, you'll create new objects and references and trees and so forth, but you won't see human-meaningful filesystem changes, probably.

Answer (score 0):

your changes have been copied into the database in `/home/user/myProject/myproject.git`.
they will not be automatically distributed to all other clones.

to see them in `home/usr/myProject` you have to make this folder a clone of the repository as well and issue a `git pull`.
it's not a good idea to have the "bare" repository within the project itself.

instead you should probably use a separate `git` repository for all your "bare" repos. 
you then `push` changes from a clone "repositoryA" to a central "bare" repository, and `pull` the changes from that central repository into another clone "repositoryB"

```
$ cd ~
$ mkdir git
$ git init --bare git/myproject.git
$ cd git clone git/myproject myProject
$ ls
git/
myProject/
$ cd myProject/
$ ls
$ cd /var/www/clonedProject/
$ git clone /home/user/git/myproject.git
$ ls
myproject
$ cd myproject
$ touch xxx.php
$ ls
xxx.php
$ git add xxx.php
$ git commit -m "TEST"
$ git push origin master
$ cd ~/myProject
$ ls
$ git pull
$ ls
xxx.php
$
```

`git` itself is a "distributed" version control system, which means that the notion of a central repository is, well, inadequate. it means, that there is not a *single* server, but can be any number of "remote" servers, including none.
however, if you have multiple clones of a single repository, it is usually advisable to have at least one shared "remote", that is *only* accessed via `git pull` and `git push`.
in theory you can clone a non-bare repository (that is: a working directory under git control) directly, but it is usually troublesome to `push` back to such a repository - mainly because you create a hierarchy of access rights.

Answer (score -1):

This might be a very good tutorial to get you started. 
[Tutorial](http://www.vogella.com/articles/Git/article.html)

Try git commit -a -m "TEST"

Comment: OP's example is equivalent.

Comment: @Alfe, that was me - 15-second comment timer.

Comment: Is it equivalent?  The option `-a` makes the difference here, doesn't it?

Comment: No difference, OP has a `git add` line already.  Semantically the `-a` is different, I guess, but it's not what the OP's trying to do, and it's certainly not an answer to the question.

Comment: I think it is.  My approach would have been to use `git commit -m "TEST" xxx.php`, but I think the option `-a` does it also.

Comment: @Alfe, fine, but you're wrong.  The `git add` already staged that file to be commited, and doing `-a` might include other files the OP doesn't want.

Answer (score -1):

Have you made a connection between your lokal repo and the remote repo?

Try:
**git remote add origin /home/user/myProject/**

Comment: He cloned it from there, the remote is added automatically.